# How can I derive from an existing Operator in Python?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

When creating a new Blender Operator, you'll derive the class from `bpy.types.Operator`, like this:

```
import bpy

class MyShinyOp(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'object.my_shiny_operator'
    bl_label = "Operator"

   # ... and so on and so forth
```

My current understanding is that most operators should derive from `bpy.types.Operator` just like above. After registration, I should see this operator as

```
bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_my_shiny_operator
```

But what if I want to **extend** an already existing one, like

```
bpy.types.MESH_OT_primitive_monkey_add
```

I cannot derive from it, as it isn't a class any more, it is a registered Operator - a class instance. So this code will fail:

```
class MyShinyOp(bpy.types.MESH_OT_primitive_monkey_add)
```

Is there a way to get a reference to the class itself? Is it around somewhere just like user written classes? Or is this somehow wrapped C++ stuff? Is it possible to derive from existing Operators at all?

Comment: @zeffii I do have the mentioned operator available, it's coming from a plugin. Honestly it doesn't matter which one, I'm asking this as a generic question. I'd be interested if this can be done at all, as it would allow to customize Blender further in a very elegant way.

Comment: If you have the addon for that operator, then `from that_addon import thatoperator` is your best bet.

Comment: @batFINGER thanks, I was aware of that, but how would I go about, let's say, bpy.types.MESH_OT_primitive_monkey_add ? I don't know where to find the source file for that to check what classes are available. Still it would be nice to be able to extend said operator.