# msgbus.subscribe_rna() to an operator?

Tags: python, scripting, operator

I'm trying to find a way to get notified by the operator *bpy.ops.object.transform_apply()* so every time my users are applying an object scale I can re-calculate it's square_area property.

But I have a hard time figuring out how I can get notified when the user is using such native operator?
So I did try to play with msgbus, **but it seem that msgbus cannot subscribes to any Operators, am I wrong?**

is there a way I can get notified when my user is using a (native) operator?

```
# Here's the msgbus snippets I tried (failed at first glance):

def fct():
    print("I'm subscribing to an operator")

bpy.msgbus.clear_by_owner('transform_apply') #only one subs per owner allowed
bpy.msgbus.subscribe_rna(key= bpy.types.OBJECT_OT_transform_apply , owner='transform_apply', args=(), notify=fct, options={'PERSISTENT'} )
                             #or bpy.ops.object.transform_apply.get_rna_type() to get type? not working too
```

Following [this Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64638/how-can-i-derive-from-an-existing-operator-in-python)